# Need a tool for pdf editing

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, master-pdf-editor, pdfsam

I am a windows user who has switched to ubuntu 20.04 recently, so far I am satisfied with ubuntu. The solo problem is pdf editing i am unabe to find a decent pdf editor with text editing,can u suggest me any app? Or any other way?

Comment: The first answer in the duplicated post, LibreOffice Draw, works for me and it comes with Ubuntu, nothing to download and it is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not finding what your looking for in the Ubuntu software repositories, you might want to use WINE and try setting up the windows program you're already familiar with. WINE is a valuable utility and extremely useful when what you're looking for just isn't there.
Native Linux programs are always preferred but sometimes the better option is what you already know.